# Api call: Call for key & value to a list and then Loop for value in another API call

Tags: json, api, loops, python-requests

i used Canvas api to call for information such as user ID, log in and log out time...but the APIs can only call for one user at a time, so i made this code to first call for a list of user IDs:

```
import requests
import json
def get_all_time_entries():
    url_address = "mywebsite.com/api/v1/courses/1111/users?per_page=50"  
    headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + "this is my bearer"
}
all_time_entries = []
for page in range(1,15):
    url = "mywebsite.com/api/v1/courses/1111/users?per_page=50&page="+str(page)
    response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers).json()        
    all_time_entries.append(response)       
    
return all_time_entries

print(get_all_time_entries())
```

I've managed to call for a list of users like this:

```
{
    "created_at": "time",
    "email": "email",
    "id": ID number, (***)
    "integration_id": null,
    "login_id": "email",
    "name": "Name",
    "short_name": "Name ",
    "sis_import_id": 111,
    "sis_user_id": "Name ",
    "sortable_name": ", Name "
},
```

Now i want to use a new loop to call for API with this link: mywebsite.com/api/v1/audit/authentication/users/:user_id (:user_id are the IDs got in the last api call of mine, marked with (***)) and get all the information to a list. How should i use loop with all those IDs?

Answer (score 0):

i've managed to find a solution for calling next APIs based on the value i got from the previous list with this code:

```
import requests
import json
def get_all_time_entries():

    url = "mywebsite.com/api/v1/courses/1111/users?per_page=50"  
    headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + "this is my bearer",}
    uri = "mywebsite.com/api/v1/audit/authentication/users/" 

    result = []
    all_time_entries = []

    # loop through all pages and return list of users of certain pages
    for page in range(1,15):

        url = "mywebsite.com/api/v1/courses/1111/users?per_page=50&page="+str(page)
        response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers).json()        
    all_time_entries.append(response)       

    return all_time_entries

# Search for id value in all_time_entries

    value = [res['id'] for res in all_time_entries]

# Loop through user log in api call by 'id'

    for x in value:
        url = "mywebsite.com/api/v1/audit/authentication/users/"+str(x)
        callback = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers).json()        
    result.append(callback)
    return result
print(get_all_time_entries())
```

Now the problem is this code keeps returning the value of the "all_time_entries" not the "result" one. i've also tried to add a certain value for the list "all_time_entries" (with no loops and calls):

```
all_time_entries = [{'id': 11, 'name': 'name', 'created_at': '2021-01-23T22:34:30+07:00', 'sortable_name': ', name', 'short_name': 'name', 'sis_user_id': 'name@email.com', 'integration_id': None, 'sis_import_id': 1, 'login_id': 'name@email.com', 'email': 'name@email.com'}, {'id': 22, 'name': 'name2', 'created_at': '2021-01-23T22:34:19+07:00', 'sortable_name': ', name2', 'short_name': 'name2', 'sis_user_id': 'name2@email.com', 'integration_id': None, 'sis_import_id': 1, 'login_id': 'name2@email.com', 'email': 'name2@email.com'}]
```

...and it worked
So i dont know if this method cannot work with a very long list or something, and is there a way to work with long list?